# Why seems to have padding on this p background?

Tags: html, css

I have the follow html code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
 <a href="id">
  <img src="file">
   <p class="titulo-noticia">The title</p>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="col">
 <a href="id">
  <img src="file">
   <p class="titulo-noticia">Another title</p>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
```

This must show a row with two images with a footer that it is the title.

The css is the following:

```
.col{
    display: table-cell;
}

.row{
    display: row;
}


.titulo-noticia{
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

My problem is that the `<p>` have a size of 1196*51, but the background color not fullfill this size. I attach an image:

[image]

The black color is not the full size of `<p>` tag.

How can achieve to fullfill the p with the color?

Comment: That's not padding, that's margin. So set that to `0`.

Comment: And `bottom`, `left`, `right` have no effect whatsoever btw., unless you `position` the element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand ur question since you did not formulate it that clearm, the extra width and height might a margin, try:

```
.titulo-noticia{
 margin: 0;
}
```

Instead of a screenshot try to include some more code so we can see for our selfs what the problem is:)

Hope this helped.

Comment: that was the solution! Thank you Jasper.

Answer (score 0):

This rule

```
.titulo-noticia{
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

can be reduced to

```
.titulo-noticia{
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Everything else has no relevance in this situation. But if there is a gap as you describe, you should add `margin: 0` to that rule - this will reset any margin which is inherited from another rule.

BTW: There is no `display: row` - that DIV will simply remain a block element. (there *is* `display: table-row` , though - maybe you want that...)